# Skype and dropbox installation problems and Nvidia problems

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, skype, dropbox

hi guys  i recently installed the new LTS OF Ubuntu ( 14.04) and i am having problems installing Skype and Dropbox. I am downloading the files from the official website . Also it seems that the this release of Ubuntu is recognizing my nvidia card however it downloads drives for the previous model of my laptop but i still have problems while watching YouTube videos and movies.

Comment: I did fresh installation for now and my advice is first - to use default open-source driver Nvidia (nouveau), you will avoid many problems with third-party software. Skype not starting etc... Second - if you have problems even with installation, there will be something missing, but your description is so vague, that I am not able to say, what. I have both, Skype and Dropbox installed on x86-64, so it is possible to install it.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that there is a bug in installing external deb packages in Ubuntu 14.04.     They are aware of it but nothing has been done as far as I can tell.

However the posted work-around is to use sudo command form the terminal:

sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb

However, I have tried this with Dropbox it to install.   Also the package in the Ubuntu store is as of yesterday out of date.

You should also update your repositories for Dropbox in Trusty.

Cheers and Good Luck